# Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils

Tags: magento2, error, blocks, overrides

I want to override below block file

```
/var/www/html/dg/vendor/magento/module-gift-card/Block/Sales/Order/Item/Renderer.php
```

I made this file

```
/var/www/html/dg/app/code/Drummondgolf/Orderemail/Block/Sales/Order/Item/Renderer.php
```

I am getting below error

> Errors during compilation:
>           Drummondgolf\Orderemail\Block\Sales\Order\Item\Renderer
>           Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils. Actual type: \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency; File: 
>       /var/www/html/dg/app/code/Drummondgolf/Orderemail/Block/Sales/Order/Item/Renderer.php

```
<?php

namespace Drummondgolf\Orderemail\Block\Sales\Order\Item;


class Renderer extends \Magento\GiftCard\Block\Sales\Order\Item\Renderer
{
   protected $_currency;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency $currency
    )
    {        
        $this->_currency = $currency;        
        parent::__construct($context,$currency);
    }

    // The below function is created to get currency symbol for Gift card products
    // Jira Task No: DG-684
    // Author: Arjun
    // Date: 21, May 2019

    public function getCurrentCurrencySymbol()
    {   
        return $this->_currency->getCurrencySymbol();
    }  
}
```

Comment: please attach code

Comment: Have you fixed this issue?